# React Update Array of Object if Object has a matching value in another Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, filter

I'm struggling to get the following to work.

I have an array of values:

```
const active = ['1', '3', '5']
```

I want to when compare this list to an array of objects (the key userid):

```
[{
    userid: '1',
    username: 'peter'
}, {
    userid: '2',
    username: 'steve'
}, {
    userid: '3',
    username: 'ted'
}]
```

And then produce an update array of objects that includes an active column:

```
data = [{
    userid: '1',
    username: 'peter',
    active: true
}, {
    userid: '2',
    username: 'steve',
    active: false
}, {
    userid: '3',
    username: 'ted',
    active: true
}]
```

Following is an attempt I've made (sorry its well off the mark)...

```
    Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
        key.filter((userid) => data.indexOf(data.userid) => active)
    })
```

I've also seen this error message so the array of objects needs to be extendable:

```
js map Error: An error occurred while selecting the store state: Cannot add property isApproved, object is not extensible.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const active = ['1', '3', '5']

const input = [{
  userid: '1',
  username: 'peter'
}, {
  userid: '2',
  username: 'steve'
}, {
  userid: '3',
  username: 'ted'
}];

const res = input.map(x => {
  const flag = active.some(y => y === x.userid)
  return {
    userid: x.userid,
    username: x.username,
    active: flag
  }
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const active = ['1', '3', '5'];

const users = [{
  userid: '1',
  username: 'peter'
}, {
  userid: '2',
  username: 'steve'
}, {
  userid: '3',
  username: 'ted'
}];

const data = users.map(user => ({
  userid: user.userid,
  username: user.username,
  active: active.includes(user.userid)
}));

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a slight rewrite of your solution

```
const active = ['1', '3', '5']
const origData = [{
    userid: '1',
    username: 'peter'
}, {
    userid: '2',
    username: 'steve'
}, {
    userid: '3',
    username: 'ted'
}]

const data = origData.map(o => {
const newObj = o;
newObj.active = active.indexOf(o.userid) > -1
return newObj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `map` and `includes` should simplify.

```js
const active = ["1", "3", "5"];

const users = [
  {
    userid: "1",
    username: "peter"
  },
  {
    userid: "2",
    username: "steve"
  },
  {
    userid: "3",
    username: "ted"
  }
];

const data = users.map(x => ({ ...x, active: active.includes(x.userid) }));

console.log(data);
```